# Set map from Helm install command

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following chart:

```
deployment:
  envVars:
    - name: FIRST
      value: first
    - name: SECOND
      value: second
```

I would like to append an extra name/value pair to the chart via the `--set` command in Helm.
The documentation at https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#the-format-and-limitations-of---set doesn't seem to help me.

I've tried to pass `--set deployment.envVars[0].name=APPEND,deployment.envVars[0].value=yes` but it says `no matches found`.

Using Helm 2.10.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try escape square brackets `[]` with backslash `\` in your command, like this `--set deployment.envVars\[0\].name=APPEND,deployment.envVars\[0\].value=yes`.

Answer (score 2):

In ZSH, this should do it:

```
helm [...] --set 'ingress.annotations.nginx\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io\/proxy-body-size'=8m
```

Make sure to properly escape all slashes and dots which aren't object nesting level delimiters in the actual keys of the map, to avoid improper rendering.